# Proving a set function is continuous from below

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Somebody please help me with this: $\mathcal{C}$ is the class of intervals *I* in $\mathbb{R}$ such that *I* = (*−∞*, *b*],(*a*, *b*], or (*a*,*∞*), where −*∞* < *a* < *b* < *∞*. Let *F* be a distribution function on $\mathbb{R}$ and define the set function *µ* on $\mathcal{C}$ by putting

*µ*((*a*, *b*]) = *F*(*b*) − *F*(*a*),

*µ*((*−∞*, *b*]) = *F*(*b*) − *F*(*−∞*),

*µ*((*a*,*∞*)) = *F*(*∞*) − *F*(*a*),

where *F*(−∞) =$\lim \limits_{x \to +-∞}$*F*(x) $\quad$ and $\quad$ *F*(∞) =$\lim \limits_{x \to +∞}$*F*(x)

Either of the above two limits can be infinite, depending on whether *F* is unbounded below or above.

How can it be proven that *µ* is continuous from below on $\mathcal{C}$? I am having difficulty because for this proof we cannot make the assumption that *F* is left-continuous. Instead, what can we infer about a sequence {$b_n$} for which ($a_n$, $b_n$] ↑ (*a*, *b* ], where *a* < *b*.

Comment: What information do you have about $F$?...

Comment: This is all of the information